# CalendarView, need sample

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm building an application using `CalendarView`. My issue is, that I don't find the way to customize the calendar style.

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendario_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I show this screen, I get the month's name and the year, like in the photo.

[image: Sample photo]

How can I customize the `CalendarView` style?

Comment: you can't customise CalanderView, DatePicker and TimePicker .

Comment: so, how can I show the numbers of the month? There are some attributes to customize the CalendarView...But I can't see nothing...because i can't get the days numbers. I need an example! Is what I'm asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for designing the calendar you can try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style) 
and change the

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

this might also help you [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949183/calendarview-clickable-android)